# Is there a solution to the error: The argument type 'Stream<UserModel?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream?'

Tags: flutter

Is there a solution to the error: The argument type 'Stream<UserModel?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream?'.

My Code

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<UserModel>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

UserModel is a class

```
class UserModel {
  final String? uid;
  UserModel({this.uid});
}
```

AuthService class

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  UserModel? _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user) {
    return user != null ? UserModel(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  Stream<UserModel?> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges()
        .map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

  Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      User user = result.user!;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);

    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: What is `AuthService().user` is returning?

Comment: a Firebase user

Comment: Could you share a snippet of the AuthService class and user attribure.

Comment: added it to the question

Answer (score 2):

In your provider you say that you will provide `Stream<UserModel>`, but you actually pass the stream with a nullable value `Stream<UserModel?>`.

Update your provider type argument:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<UserModel?>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```